# For Loop help, checking prime numbers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
        for (int i = lo; i <= hi; i++)  
    {
        boolean isPrime = true;  // each value of i starts out assuming it IS prime
        // Write a loop below that divides i by 2,3,4,5 etc upto i/2 
        // If at any time you find a divisor that evenly divides i
        // Then set isPrime to false    

        /* your prime checking loop HERE */
        for (int j = 2; j <= hi / 2; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }   
        // DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY LINE BELOW
        if ( isPrime )
            System.out.print( i + " " );
    }
```

Okay, here is the code I currently have and i'm assuming the problem lies within. The program takes a text input file and sets the first value as lo (in the text demo I have, the lo = 3 and hi = 73.) For whatever reason, the only numbers that are output as 'prime' start at 41 and then go totally fine after that. I have no idea why the first half of the numbers aren't being outputted at all.

Keep in mind I must use for loops for this project, methods and such are not in the 'vocabulary' at the moment. Trying to keep it simple. I'd appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the comment block again.  It says to loop until i/2.  You're looping until hi/2.

The issue is that you keep using modulus of the number on itself.

3 % 3 is zero, but 3 is prime.

Comment: Holy hell, can't believe I missed that. Thanks a bunch! Works great now!

Comment: Glad I could help!  Make sure you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the prime checking loop, choose one:

```
for (int j = 2; j < i / 2; j++)
```

or

```
for (int j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j++)
```